# How much could £40pa rent you in 1972?

Tags: england, london

In [this case](https://www.bailii.org/ew/cases/EWCA/Civ/1972/4.html) a premise was rented by the Duke of Westminster to someone in Pimlico (reasonably central London, at least by today's standards, and a fairly expensive area if i'm not mistaken) for £10 per quarter. I ran it through an inflation calculator and that's worth simply about £500 in today's money. That still only works out to about £42 per month. And apparently that was a place that was big enough to run a brothel out of!

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why is it necessary for this place to have been rented out at market rates?

Comment: I suppose not. Do you know why it might not be?

Comment: The £40 was the annual "ground rent". The original lease in 1930 would have involved the purchaser paying a substantial capital sum to the Duke, to "buy" the lease, and £40 per year thereafter. The lease was later sold by the original tenant (or a successor) to the gentleman occupying it in 1972. It seems he paid £9,000 to his predecessor for it in 1957. In effect he bought the flat for £9,000 subject to a £40 pa payment. The £40 may have started lower and then risen linked to inflation. This is a common arrangement in English property law.

Comment: Well, this is all very informative and I think explains the question significantly better than the earlier comment above. But is it in fact a common arrangement in EPL? Or was it previously and has since faded a bit from prominence?

Comment: Hi @Seekinganswers - Yes it is very common with leasehold properties, which most flats are. However it is not as common now since, if I understand corectly, newly built properties can no longer be sold on that basis, since 2022 I think. Perhaps Law stackexchange could give you more specific information., now that you know the basic principle.

Comment: It seems i don't have a clear enough understanding of the basic principle to be able to frame a question on law.se well enough for it to be received there. Is there a specific statute of 2022 that you're referring to?

Comment: @Seekinganswers  https://www.gov.uk/guidance/leasehold-reform-ground-rent-act-2022

Comment: Yes. It is always difficult to ask a question without knowing at least some of the answer. !! Here is a link to the Leasehold Reform (Ground Rent) Act 2022. https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/the-leasehold-reform-ground-rent-act-user-guidance/leasehold-reform-ground-rent-act-2022-guidance-for-leaseholders-landlords-and-managing-agents      I'm afraid I'm not an expert but recognised that the £40 in your question was not really pure rent. Hope it helps, sorry I can' be more help.

Comment: @davidlol very helpful indeed.

Comment: And @DaveGremlin sorry for the silly question, after asking it it only took a moment for me to think to google "ground rent leasehold reform 2022" to find an act of nearly an identical name complete with statutory guidance and a host of blogs introducing it. Thanks anyway for the link.